# Unable to update array aws Dynamo

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

iam trying to update json array.i have a table in dynamoDb.i successfully inserted the json data to dynamo using put method.

> Partition key : *_id* ,   Type : S

This is my json data saved into the database.

```
{
    "_id": "001",
    "email": "teacher1@gmail.com",
    "class": {
        "student_list": []
    }
}
```

But i cant updated json array ***student_list*** using key ***email***.
 I have following code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "testTable1",
    Key: {
        "email": "teacher1@gmail.com",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set class.student_list = list_append (class.student_list, :studentEmail)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":studentEmail": "manaf@gmail.com"
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};

docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

But i got an error message like this

```
Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: S",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2016-07-18T14:31:44.978Z",
  "requestId": "378NSB5RVB1TNI0PB1Q3OH67V3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

What is the actual issue related with this?

Comment: what is the dynamodb data type of attribute "class" and "student_list"?

Comment: "class" Type : Map ,  "student_list" Type : List .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html

Operand type must be contained in a list.

*"The new element must be contained in a list, for example to add 2 to a list, the operand would be [2]"*

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i need to append student_list by string elements.

Comment: can't you convert the string "user@domain.com" to an array of only that element before executing the query?

Comment: thanks Conti, i just change studentEmail from string to list. But another error message produced "The provided key element does not match the schema". its working fine using key as _id(partition key) instead of "email" key. But i need to update using email.

Comment: Whenever you specify a Key, you also have to specify the type: Key:{'_id': {'S':'001'},'email':{'S':"teacher1@gmail.com"}}